# How to make indentation in html ul li tag

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have unordered list which has bulleted text within. I need to indent the list items in line. However for long running text, the style is not working as expected. I should make it aligned within the border box. Here is the css code

```
ul{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    list-style: disc inside none;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is the example HTML

```
<div style="padding:20px">
    <ul>
        <li>Should be minimum of 8 characters</li>
        <li>A long running text A long running text A long running text A long running text A long running text</li>
        <li>Should have at least one number</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

JS Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/jHJXq/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/jHJXq/3/

```
ul{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    list-style: disc outside none;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
}
```

I changed the list style to "outside" and gave some extra padding to the left.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Add style to the `LI`:

```
li {
   margin-left:15px;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change the list-style from inside to outside

```
list-style: disc outside none;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    list-style: disc;
    padding:10px;
}

li{
    margin-left:10px;
}
```